# How to convert 'start', 'stop' and 'step' values in a for loop

Tags: python, math

Given the `start`, `stop` and `step` values, where `start` > `stop` and `step` < `0`, how can I convert the values so that `start` < `stop` and `step` > `0` and use these values in a for loop that can yield the same index but in a reverse way. In other words, what should be the mathematical formula to use to set variables `converted_start` and `converted_stop` below?

```
start = 8
stop  = 0
step  = -2

for index in range(start, stop, step):
    print(index)   # prints 8, 6, 4 and 2


converted_start = ...     # convert `start`
converted_start = ...     # convert `stop`
converted_step  = -step   # convert `step`

for index in range(converted_start, converted_stop, converted_step):
    print(index)   # prints 2, 4, 6 and 8
```

Comment: `c_start = stop - step; c_stop = start - step`?

Comment: Thanks - Unfortunately, I don't think it works properly.

Comment: @user7698505, please revise your question with possible inputs and expected outputs that you're looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here come the formula:

```py
def reverse_range(start, stop, step):
  new_start_offset = (stop - start) % step
  if new_start_offset == 0:
    new_start_offset = step
  new_start = stop - new_start_offset
  new_stop = start - step
  new_step = -step
  return new_start, new_stop, new_step
```

Here come the tests:

```py
def print_range(start, stop, step):
  for i in range(start, stop, step):
    print(i, end=',')
  print()

print_range(0, 8, 2)
0,2,4,6,
print_range(*reverse_range(0,8,2))
6,4,2,0,

print_range(0, 9, 2)
0,2,4,6,8,
print_range(*reverse_range(0,9,2))
8,6,4,2,0,

print_range(8, 0, -2)
8,6,4,2,
print_range(*reverse_range(8, 0, -2))
2,4,6,8,

print_range(9, 0, -2)
9,7,5,3,1,
print_range(*reverse_range(9, 0, -2))
1,3,5,7,9,
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the underlying problem is, but for the case you describe, it's easiest to use the built-in [`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#reversed):

```py
start = 8
stop  = 0
step  = -2

for index in reversed(range(start, stop, step)):
  print(index)

# prints 2, 4, 6, 8
```

Comment: Thanks but without a built-in function! :)

Answer (score 0):

You're almost right,

```
start = 8
stop  = 0
step  = -2

for index in range(start, stop, step):
    print(index)   # prints 8, 6, 4 and 2
    
new_start, new_stop = stop , start - step
for index in range(new_start, new_stop, -step):
    print(index) #prints 0, 2, 4, 6 and 8

new_start, new_stop = stop - step , start - step
for index in range(new_start, new_stop, -step):
    print(index) #prints 2, 4, 6 and 8
```

Tweak the code accordingly for your need.

Comment: Thanks for the solution - the third loop works well and as expected for `start = 8`. Unfortunately, it doesn't cover the situation where `start = 9`. How can your solution be tweaked so that it covers this situation too?

Comment: @user7698505, Can you please tell what's your expected output for ```start = 9``` ?

Comment: Thanks for your time - I was expecting `9`, `7`, `5`, `3`, `1`

Answer (score 0):

My solution is doing exactly what you mentioned even when you change variables.

```
import math
start = 8
stop  = 0
step  = -2

for index in range(start, stop, step):
    print(index)  # prints 8, 6, 4 and 2

calculation1    = (math.ceil((start - stop)/(-step)))*(-step)
calculation2    = (start - calculation1) - step
converted_start = calculation2                # convert `start`
converted_stop  = start - step                # convert `stop`
converted_step  = -step                       # convert `step`

for index in range(converted_start, converted_stop, converted_step):
    print(index)  # prints 2, 4, 6 and 8
```

I have split calculation into two parts (calculation1&2) for better understanding, u can put that all in same line.

Answer (score -3):

```
 start = 8
 stop  = 0
 step  = -2
 
 for index in range(start, stop, step):
     print(start - index - step)

Result:
2
4
6
8
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/29100293)

Comment: @KevalDave I don't see how this should be a comment. This is an honest attempt to answer the question. If you think it is not a good one, you can downvote the answer, but don't vote to delete if it's actually trying to answer. You can read [You're doing it wrong: A plea for sanity in the Low Quality Posts queue](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287563/6045800)